# How to specify color condition in ggplot maintaining the color palette in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatterplot with ggplot. I have some values that are way bigger than the other, but it is important to show them. However, including these values prevent to see the changes in the color for the other values.

I would like to use a palette for the continuous variable, but specify a condition to color all the values higher than a certain values using the same color.

Reproducible example:

```
data = iris[1:3] # example data

data[1:5, 3] <- data[1:5, 3] * 150 # adding very high data

# plot
ggplot(data)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(
    name = "color",
    direction = -1,
    option="magma"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image]

It is impossible to see all the values below the high ones.

Is it possible to keep the viridis palette and specify that all the values greater than the 3 quartile (or whatever value) of the Petal.Length should be colored in black?

Comment: One thought is that you could set any of the outliers to NA in your data set. Then scale_color_gradient allows you to set a color for na.value. The default is "grey50".

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your dataset in two:

```
data = iris[1:3] # example data

data[1:5, 3] <- data[1:5, 3] * 150 # adding very high data

val_75_percentile <- quantile(data$Petal.Length)[["75%"]]

outliers <- data[data$Petal.Length > val_75_percentile, ]
data <- data[data$Petal.Length < val_75_percentile, ]

# plot
ggplot(data)+
  geom_point(data = outliers, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width), 
             color = "black") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length)) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(
    name = "color",
    direction = -1,
    option="magma"
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image]